# CSS shadow awesome effect

Tags: css, shadow

I have wasted 2 days to create a shadow effect [like here](https://www.shutterstock.com/ru/image-vector/minimal-paper-cut-infographics-design-202379794).
You see, the front white buttons look not flat, don't know how to describe. I bet this is because of box shadow effect, inset or something like that. But I can't make the same.

Can anyone help to make such a button with the same design, effect?

[My example](https://codepen.io/iTaurus85/pen/wEXZOQ)

```css
.button {
  background-size: 400% auto;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, rgb(247, 212, 167), #eef2f3);
  border-radius: 7%;
  box-shadow: inset 4px -4px 1px 1px rgb(252, 205, 144), inset -4px 4px 1px 1px white, -15px 25px 25px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
  transition: all .2s linear;
  left: 0;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="button main-circle"></div>
```

Comment: I think your best bet is to usea background image

Comment: I think what you should use is a background image with the same code with another tile placed at exact position of the shadow, then it will give the effect of the shadow and edges of your background will not be blurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea using some gradient and pseudo elements:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #e0e1e6;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #b9b7dc, #a7a7c9);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 30%;
  left: -32%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid #fefefe;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #e0e0e0, #fefefe);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 30%;
    left: -31%;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,0.3),rgba(0,0,0,0.1));
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: skewY(11deg) scaleX(1.15);
    filter: blur(4px);
    transform-origin: top left;
}
body {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```